# Tastypie URL Mapping, Mapping with mysql database

Tags: tastypie

I have one table:

Table Name: "blog"

```
version_id(Primary Key) | blog_id | version_name | title | status
1                       | 21      | draft        | test  | 1
2                       | 21      | live         | test  | N/A
```

Users will use this url:-

```
GET: v1/blogs/{blog_id}/draft
PUT: v1/blogs/{blog_id}/draft
```

but tastypie will create url according to primary key: -

```
GET: v1/blogs/{version_id}
PUT: v1/blogs/{version_id}
```

According to me Pseudo code should be:-

```
select version_id 
from blog 
where version_id = 1 and version_name = draft
```

and using version_id I can create:-

```
v1/blogs/{version_id}
```

But I am not able to write url mapping in tastypie,

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would setup the `blog` table as follows

```
id | blog_id | version | version_name | title | status
1  | 21      | 1       | draft        | test  | 1
2  | 21      | 2       | live         | test  | N/A
```

Its good practice to always have a unique identifier for a table. I'm not quite sure if thats what you meant by `version_id` since your naming is confusing

tastypie will use the `id` field, but with that information you can easily find the parent/published blog and change it (since I guess that's what you're after). I'm also not sure what blog_id refers to. Conceptially it refers to the record (ie the id field), but perhaps your setup is different. I suggest you relook at your modelling to make sure its as simple as possible.

Comment: **version_id** is same as ID.

Comment: In that case, don't have id, version and blog_id. Having blog_id on the blog table is confusing. Just use id on the blog table.